# Reactjs - Search with a dropdown

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, searchbar, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap and I have a `Navbar` with an `Input` inside it. As, I type in that `Input` I want a dropdown to show the possible results. I have got all the backend queries and frontend `onChange` functions structured in mind.

**All I need is the proper markup** for that. I already have an `Input`. Now, no dropdown should come when its empty but while I am typing a dropdown should appear.

Which `reactstrap/html` elements can I use for that combination of `Input` and `Dropdown`.

---

This is the mess that I came up with:

```
<Dropdown
    isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
    toggle={this.toggleDropdown}
    >
    <DropdownToggle caret>
        <Input
            type='text'
            name='keyword'
            placeholder='Search for reddit'
            value={this.state.keyword}
        />
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Option 3</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Option 4</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

---

Additional functions:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
        keyword: '',
        dropdownOpen: false,
        subreddits: [],
        posts: [],
        users: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this)
}

toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        dropdownOpen: !prev.dropdownOpen
    }))
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }, () => {
        this.state.keyword.length !== 0 &&
            this.setState({
                subreddits: this.filterSubreddits()
            })
    })
}
```

I am not able to type anything in the `Input`. Also, the `Input` is inside a DropDown button which looks so ugly!!

[image: Edit r57mo0946m]

Comment: You could use the great `Downshift` package to achieve this https://github.com/paypal/downshift

Comment: Is there an example present with that package?